# Property of excision of Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Please what is the difference between these two excision property:

Let $X$ a topological space, $A$ a sub-space of $X$ and $U\subset A$ such that $\overline{U}\subset \stackrel{\circ}{A}$ . The inclusion of the pairs $(X-U,A-U)\rightarrow (X,A)$ induced an isomorphism for all $n\in \mathbb{N},$ $$H_n(X-U,A-U)\simeq H_n(X,A).$$

and :

If $A,B\subset X$ such that $X= \stackrel{\circ}{A}\cup \stackrel{\circ}{B}$ then the inclusion $e\colon (A,A\cap B)\rightarrow (X,A)$ induced an isomorphism $e_*\colon H_k(A,A\cap B)\rightarrow H_k(X,A), \forall k\in \mathbb{N}.$

Comment: The second isomorphism isn't $H_k(B,A\cap B)\to H_k(X,A)$?

Comment: @Hamou i posted an answer what do you think? in the book it is $H_n(A,A\cap B)$

Comment: Mais il faut changer le deuxième isomorphisme dans l'énoncé. $H_k(B,A\cap B)$ a la place de $H_k(A,A\cap B)$

Comment: Oui ou $B=X-U$ mais l'inclusion reste juste parce que on a pas d’hypothèses  sur $A$ et $B$ juste que $X=\overset{º}{A}\cup \overset{º}{B}$

Comment: Mais comparer avec le résultat que vous avez démontré! ce n'est pas la même chose.

Comment: Je pense que c'est impossible de démontrer quoi que ce soit avec cette forme actuelle  non ?

Comment: Revoire l'énoncé originale.il ya deux choses $H_k(B,A\cap B)\to H_k(X,A)$ ou $H_(A,A\cap B)\to H_k(X,B)$.

Comment: l'énoncé originale est comme je l'ai mis seulement les deux théorèmes ne proviennent pas du même livre

Comment: Pour la 2éme implication Si j'ai $A,B$ tel que $X=\overset{º}{A}\cup\overset{º}{B}$ on a que $\overset{º}{B}= X\setminus \overset{º}{A}$ peut on dire directement qu'il existe $U\subset A$ avec $B=X-U$ ou $\overline{U}\subset A$ ? merci

Comment: Ceci $\overset{º}{B}= X\setminus \overset{º}{A}$ n'est pas vrai en generale sauf si l'intersection est vide.

Comment: Oui c'est vrai et comment on fait, je peux dire qu'il existe un $U\subset A$ tel que $\overline{U}\subset \overset{º}{A}$ avec $B=X-U$ ?

Comment: On peut considérer $U=X-B$ comme $X=\overset{º}{B}\cup \overset{º}{A}$ on a que $\overline{U}\subset A$d'ou le résultat

Comment: Oui avec $U=X\setminus B$ ca marche.

Comment: Ok merci beaucoup donc ma réponse est juste ^_^

Comment: Je dois ajouter que le morphisme $C_k(A, A\cap B) \to C_k(X, A)$, sur les chaines, est toujours égal à zero. Alors, on a que le morphisme $H_k(A,A\cap B) \to H_k(X, A)$ égale zero.

Answer (score 1):

From the first definition we have that $X=\stackrel{\circ}{X-U}\cup \stackrel{\circ}{A}$  because $\overline{U}\subset \stackrel{\circ}{A}$ and $\stackrel{\circ}{X-U}=X-\overline{U}$

then if i put $B=X-U$ i obtain that $H_n(B,B\cap A)=H_n(X-U,A-U)$

where $A$ is the same and $X-U=B$ in this case $X=\stackrel{\circ}{A}\cup \stackrel{\circ}{B}$

so the two definitions are equivalent

since $(B,A\cap B)\rightarrow (X,A)$ still defined an inclusion so there is no contradiction

Edit: For the second implication we choose $U=X-B$ in this way as $X=\stackrel{\circ}{A}\cup \stackrel{\circ}{B}$ we have that $\overline{U}\subset A.$ and then we have the result.

Comment: C'est bon. a condition de corrigé l'énoncé! ce que vous avez demontrer que le premier énoncé implique le dexième.

Answer (score 1):

See the Theorem $1$ and $2$ [here](http://www.math.ru.nl/~mgroth/teaching/algtopI14/Lecture06.pdf), where there is equivalent.